# What does “a man of comforts” mean?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean when we say someone is "**not a man of comforts**" ? Does this mean he's not a rich man?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's one meaning.  "Man of comforts" is a rather old-fashioned expression, meaning a person who is accustomed to having the "finer things in life" about himself, so by extension well-off to the point of being wealthy.  So, a person who is "not a man of comforts" is either a well-off person of simple tastes, or a poor person.

A little research yields examples that illustrate the different uses (first, the poor man):

> One day, before the city
>       Of Brussels, in Brabant,
>       We saw with fear and pity
>       This man of comforts scant,
>
> – The Ladies' Garland and Family Magazine, 1846

and (the well-off man)

> Tiernan, it proved, was a man of comforts, holding a well-padded county job.
>
> –  Mounted Justice: True Stories of the Pennsylvania State Police, 1922

and (the well-off man with simple tastes)

> Robert Pattinson of 'Twilight' not a Man of Comforts
>
> [Source: The Examiner](http://www.examiner.com/article/robert-pattinson-of-twilight-not-a-man-of-comforts-on-reege)

Answer (score 1):

It mostly means the speaker/writer is seriously out of touch with contemporary English usage. There are only [7 instances of "**a man of comforts**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20man%20of%20comforts%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books, so it's obviously difficult to say the words have any inherent special meaning beyond the literal interpretation.

In fact, the earliest (1660) of those 7 written instances apparently does refer directly to *comforts* as *elements of cheer in an otherwise woeful life*. And it would be perfectly possible for someone of modest means to say...

> *"Why would I want to win the Lottery? I have all the comforts of life in my own little home already"*

Of course, a richer man might have *more comfortable* "comforts of life" than the "poor, but content" man. But the above usage isn't uncommon, so it's not unreasonable to interpret OP's phrase as meaning *a person who both has **and appreciates** the comforts of life* - indicating an *attitude* to "comfortable things" rather than possession of the means with which to buy the best ones.

---

But most likely if you *do* come across the expression used today, it'll be a "pseudo-archaic" allusion to...

> [**comfortably off**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/comfortably-off) *- rich enough to pay for everything you need*

...which *is* a "current expression".

Comment: This may not answer the O.P.'s question, but I agree with it entirely, and I think the contribution is valuable.

Comment: @J.R.: I think it *does* - we're not here to teach learners how to interpret pre-Victorian texts. Current usage is very rare anyway, and often won't reflect the earlier sense.

Comment: Current usage (rare as it is) has a slightly tongue-in-cheek flavor to me.  Makin fun of the highfalutin, so to speak.

Comment: @Bob: Indeed. The usage is so rare that I think it's almost meaningless to say what it "means" in any general sense. But checking the handful of instances on Google Internet for *man of **few** comforts* makes it pretty clear that nearly always means *a man who **doesn't care much** about "comfortable" things/lifestyle*. So on reflection my "most likely" interpretation above might be overstating the case.

Comment: I've heard the expression before. It may be rare, but I'm not sure it's as [obsolete](http://www.highbeam.com/doc/1G1-65121064.html) as you're making it out to be. Moreover, Bob's answer points to a modern headline that uses the phrase. (Who knows? – maybe that's what inspired this question).

Comment: @J.R.: Well, yes. But the likes of you, me, and Bob are relatively well-read, with extensive vocabularies. People seeking enlightenment on a *learners'* site are presumably far more likely to encounter more "sloppy" usages from less "careful" sources. I found quite a few such when I just leafed through instances on the web (esp. in blogs, and other user-generated content sites).

Comment: @JR I was thinking the same thing.  :)

Comment: @Bob: I wouldn't exactly say J.R. and I are "at loggerheads" over the issue (just as well, seeing he's a mod! :), but it's not uncommon for me to be championing the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) approach to ELL answers where he thinks more detail/accuracy would be better. With this specific question, for example, I think I'd unhesitatingly delete my answer in favour of yours if we'd both posted on ELU. But here on ELL I'm inclined to think it's worth taking a somewhat different position, so I'll happily leave my contribution even though yours is clearly more accurate.

Comment: @Fumble - Imagine you're in Korea, trying to learn Korean. You come across an odd phrase in a headline, and you can't quite make heads or tails of it. You check your trusty English-Korean dictionary, but it's still elusive. So, you ask on KLL. Turns out, the phrase is a seldom-used antiquated term that's only used every now and again. Two things strike me: (1) There would be no way to know this term is outdated, unless you asked. (2) The last thing you would need is someone spouting off that "this question has no place on a _learners_ site; we're not here to teach people 19th-century Korean."

Comment: This is why I think your initial answer was valuable, but I'm not so keen on your subsequent comments. The language may be odd and quaint, but it does get used, and someone found it. They asked what it meant, and they have a right to know, irrespective of how prevalent it may or may not be.

Comment: @JR: Let's not overstate my case. I didn't say "this question has no place here" (and after all, I did actually *answer* it). Yes, anyone who asks any question that's even *close* to On Topic here should be given an answer. What I'm saying is it would be unwise for a learner to assume usages like this were actually worth *learning* and *repeating in their own use of English*. Even among native speakers the meaning and (rare) appropriate contexts are uncertain. For most learners this would be a case of "a little learning is a dangerous thing".

Comment: I didn't mean to "overstate" anything, but phrases like "we're not here to teach learners how to interpret pre-Victorian texts" and "People seeking enlightenment on a *learners'* site" [emphasis in original] do make me wince. They could be perceived as unwelcoming (though I know you didn't mean it that way). On a more positive note, I hope you'd keep your answer here _or_ on ELU; it complements Bob's quite nicely. His answer talks about the different ways the phrase can be used, yours adds a caveat that it's not a prevalent phrase in modern English. Both are valuable pieces of information.

Comment: @Fumblefingers: Your answer provides information, and so does mine.  That's my position. :)